# Null pointer exception when try to access API

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I just tried retrofit2 for my news app that I am currently working on, I tried to call my API implementation in a fragment class. But I keep getting nullpointerexception, here's my fragment code:

```
public class IgnFragment extends Fragment {


@BindView(R.id.ignNewsContainer)
RecyclerView ignNewsContainer;
Unbinder unbinder;

Call<NewsArticle> call;
public IgnFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ign, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     call = NewsApi.getApi().getArticles("ign", "top");
    getClient();
}
public void getClient(){
    call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsArticle>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsArticle> call, Response<NewsArticle> response) {
            NewsArticle newsArticle = response.body();
            NewsAdapter newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(newsArticle.getArticles(),getContext());
            ignNewsContainer.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            ignNewsContainer.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsArticle> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error","Called");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}
```

and here is my api service class:

```
public class NewsApi {
private static final String API_KEY = "________";
private static final String URL_BASE ="https://newsapi.org/v1/";


private static NewsService newsService =null;
public static NewsService getApi(){
   if(newsService == null){
       Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(getClient())
               .build();
        NewsService api = retrofit.create(NewsService.class);
   }
    return newsService;
}

public static OkHttpClient getClient(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    return  httpClient.addInterceptor(logging).build();
}

public interface  NewsService{
    @GET("articles?apiKey=" + API_KEY)
    Call<NewsArticle> getArticles(@Query("source") String source,@Query("sortBy") String sortBy);
}
```

}

and here's the error I get:

> 10-30 20:42:01.640 32640-32640/cc.codemonkey.newsportal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: cc.codemonkey.newsportal, PID: 32640
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call cc.codemonkey.newsportal.service.NewsApi$NewsService.getArticles(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at cc.codemonkey.newsportal.fragments.IgnFragment.onStart(IgnFragment.java:54)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2265)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1369)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1613)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
>                                                                               at java.lang.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this exact line

`NewsAdapter newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(newsArticle.getArticles(),getContext());`

the problem says that the newsArticle is being `null` which has been initialized here

`NewsArticle newsArticle = response.body();`

so `response.body()` is null please try to debug and to see why is it empty! when you fix this your solution should work.
And alos refer to this [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to understand more what a NullPointerException is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using retrofit2, so check please in your "News" class if you write it right like

```
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles;
```

and not

```
@SerializedName("article")  <------ article != articles
@Expose
private List<Article> articles;
```